# Overriding "Non-Existent Components" in a Loop

Tags: r, loops, igraph

I have the following network graph:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)


set.seed(123)
n=15
data = tibble(d = paste(1:n))

relations = tibble(
  from = sample(data$d),
  to = lead(from, default=from[1]),
)

graph = graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=T, vertices = data) 

V(graph)$color <- ifelse(data$d == relations$from[1], "red", "orange")

plot(graph, layout=layout.circle, edge.arrow.size = 0.2)
```

[image]

I learned how to remove all the "edges" in this graph:

```
g <- graph-E(graph)
plot(g)
```

Now, I am trying to do this same thing, but using a "loop" instead:

```
for (i in 1:15)
 for (j in 1:15) { 

graph <- graph - edge(paste0(i, "|", j)) 

}
```

But I think the problem is that the above code is trying to delete "edges" that exist, and this code does not have the ability to "skip" (override) an instance when it is commanded to delete a non-existing edge:

```
Error in delete_edges(e1, unlist(e2, recursive = FALSE)) : 
  At iterators.c:1828 : Cannot create iterator, invalid edge id, Invalid vertex id
```

Is there a way to instruct this "loop" to "skip" every instances where two edges do not have a connection and to continue until the loop is done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you want to run a `for` loop, but please find below a possible solution using the `as_edgelist()` function from the `igraph` library.

**Reprex**

- Your data

```r
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
n=15
data = tibble(d = paste(1:n))

relations = tibble(
  from = sample(data$d),
  to = lead(from, default=from[1]),
)

graph = graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=T, vertices = data) 

V(graph)$color <- ifelse(data$d == relations$from[1], "red", "orange")

plot(graph, layout=layout.circle, edge.arrow.size = 0.2)
```

[image]

- Suggested code

```r
edgelist <- as_edgelist(graph, names = TRUE)

  for (i in 1:15) { 
    
    graph <- graph - edge(paste0(edgelist[i,1], "|", edgelist[i,2])) 
    
  } 

plot(graph)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I was just curious why my "loop" I had originally written is not working!

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why did you decide to use "reprex" package? Are there any advantages to using this?

Comment: If you are familiar with "igraph" in R - can check these out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71244872/zoom-and-hide-options-for-html-widgets

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71243676/directly-adding-titles-and-labels-to-visnetwork

Comment: Hi @antonoyaro8, thank you very much for your feedback. I use the `reprex`  library to make sure that the code I post on SO is properly reproducible. Regarding your other two questions, I will think about it but it is more related to the `visNetwork` library than to the `igraph` library and I am less comfortable (and have not enough time right now to dive in). I suggest you to add the tag `visnetwork` to your questions to increase your chances to be helped by the most expert people in this field. Cheers.