# Understanding "list" and "do.call" commands

Tags: r, data-visualization, igraph, visnetwork

Over here ([Directly Adding Titles and Labels to Visnetwork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71243676/directly-adding-titles-and-labels-to-visnetwork)), I learned how to directly add titles to graphs made using the "visIgraph()" function:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)

set.seed(123)
n=15
data = data.frame(tibble(d = paste(1:n)))

relations = data.frame(tibble(
  from = sample(data$d),
  to = lead(from, default=from[1]),
))

data$name = c("new york", "chicago", "los angeles", "orlando", "houston", "seattle", "washington", "baltimore", "atlanta", "las vegas", "oakland", "phoenix", "kansas", "miami", "newark" )

graph = graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=T, vertices = data) 

V(graph)$color <- ifelse(data$d == relations$from[1], "red", "orange")

toVisNetworkData(graph) %>%
  c(., list(main = "my title", submain = "subtitle")) %>%
  do.call(visNetwork, .)
```

[image]

I also learned how to arrange the graph in a random layout:

```
visIgraph(graph) %>%
    visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle") %>%
    visOptions(highlightNearest = list(enabled = T, hover = T), 
               nodesIdSelection = T)
```

[image]

Now, I want to combine these two codes so I can keep the titles (via the visIgraph() function) and the random layout. This is the end goal that I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I tried to do this by combining these codes in different ways - but nothing seems to be working:

- Option 1:

```
    g = visIgraph(graph) %>%
        visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle") %>%
        visOptions(highlightNearest = list(enabled = T, hover = T), 
                   nodesIdSelection = T)
    
    toVisNetworkData(g) %>%
        c(., list(main = "my title")) %>%
        do.call(visNetwork, .)
```

> Error in toVisNetworkData(g) : igraph must be a igraph object

- Option 2:

```
toVisNetworkData(graph) %>% 
         c(., list(main = "my title")) %>%  visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle")
```

> Error in visIgraphLayout(., layout = "layout_in_circle") :
> graph must be a visNetwork object

```
do.call(visNetwork, .)
```

> Error in do.call(visNetwork, .) : object '.' not found

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I think I am not correctly understanding how the "do.call" and "list" commands are supposed to be used?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not a problem in the latter part. The first error is the one to focus on. "`Error in toVisNetworkData(g) : igraph must be a igraph object`". apprently `g` is not an `igraph` that the function can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below one possible solution.

**Reprex**

- Your data

```r
library(dplyr)
library(visNetwork)

set.seed(123)
n=15
data = data.frame(tibble(d = paste(1:n)))

relations = data.frame(tibble(
  from = sample(data$d),
  to = lead(from, default=from[1]),
))

data$name = c("new york", "chicago", "los angeles", "orlando", "houston", "seattle", "washington", "baltimore", "atlanta", "las vegas", "oakland", "phoenix", "kansas", "miami", "newark" )

graph = graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=T, vertices = data) 

V(graph)$color <- ifelse(data$d == relations$from[1], "red", "orange")
```

- Suggested code

```
toVisNetworkData(graph) %>%
  c(., list(main = "my title", submain = "subtitle")) %>%
  do.call(visNetwork, .) %>%
  visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle") %>% 
  visEdges(arrows = 'to')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I used your code to keep working on another problem I am currently facing, can you please look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71244872/zoom-and-hide-options-for-html-widgets Is it possible to do this?